# Matplotlib shows black window when plotting during training in keras

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

This is a callback function from keras.

```
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
    self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
    plt.plot(self.val_losses, 'g', label='Validation loss')
    plt.plot(self.losses, 'b', label='Training loss')
```

I want to plot the loss in real time using matplotlib, but what I get is a black window during training. Only after it, the figure is displayed properly.

When I save figure to a file, it also generates a proper figure, even during training. Is it possible to plot the loss in real time in this way?

[image: black window]

Answer (score 0):

I am using **TensorFlow** and facing the same problem. I solved it *partially* by using `plt.pause(0.01)` in the training loop (so you can put it in your callback function).

But this solution is not efficient at all because it will force your code to sleep for the specified period (here 0.01 second). The training will become very slow !

I know, this is not a real solution, but it is all that I found right now.